# How to write deg with an underline across the bottom of 'g'?

Tags: math-operators, underline

I want to use this notation in LaTeX:

[image],

which is different from `\underline{\deg}`. Is there any way to obtain this notation? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to smash the depth of “deg”, but also add the depth outside the `\underline` to keep the vertical spacings right.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\udeg}{%
  \vphantom{\mathrm{deg}}%
  \underline{\smash[b]{\mathrm{deg}}}
}

\begin{document}

\[
\udeg(a)\ne\deg(a)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use, if you prefer, an old package since 2019 called [ulem](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/ulem/ulem.pdf). Here there is a screenshot.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{ulem}

\begin{document}
$\uline{\smash{\deg}}(x^4+x^2)=4$
\end{document}
```

[image]

PS: The rendering of the underline is not very good for the problem with the dvi of TeXworks. https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/1450